# Digital Ocean - 18.04 Ubuntu Server Setup ERROR

Tags: ubuntu, server, terminal, digital-ocean

I am following this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04

I was at the part to run

```
 sudo apt install python3-pip python3-dev libpq-dev postgresql postgresql-contrib nginx curl
```

and it asked me to say yes or no

I left the terminal open while the server kicked me out.

But when I logged back it did not allow me to run the same code to do all the installs with the following ERROR message:

```
  E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
  E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get to know the active processes (1.process name 2. process ID) I had to run:

```
 ps aux | grep -i apt
```

Than to delete the process

```
 sudo kill -9 THAT_SPECIFIC_PROCESS_ID_COMES_HERE
```

Than rerun the installation code

```
 sudo apt install python3-pip python3-dev libpq-dev postgresql postgresql-contrib nginx curl
```