# Error in the installation of apache2 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to install apache2 server for xampp
but it shows me the error like this:-

> E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
> E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?```

even after updating so many times and removing locked apts lists

Comment: You may find more specific help on https://askubuntu.com/.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Digital Ocean - 18.04 Ubuntu Server Setup ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59116429/digital-ocean-18-04-ubuntu-server-setup-error)

Comment: This usually occurs when you have something like software centre or update manager running at the same time as doing apt-get from the command line

Answer (score 0):

run in terminal:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock*
```

then configure the packages

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```